# Implementing View.OnClickListener for the activity - method is not overriden

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

Here is my activity code:

```
public class TextsListActivity extends ActionBarActivity implements View.OnClickListener {

    @Override
    public void OnClick(View button) {

    }
}
```

Android Studio warns that `Method does not override method from its superclass` and also another warning that `TextsListActivity` should implement `onClick`. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The declaration of the method has a **lowercase** letter "*o*", you're really not overriding the one you think you are. Keep in mind that the view may or may not be a `Button`, any `View` can potentially receive a `click` event.

```
 public void onClick(View v) {} //as opposed to OnClick
```

---

**Tip:** The next time, if you press <kbd>alt</kbd><kbd>⏎</kbd> while having the cursor on an error you will be prompted with some possible solutions to the situation. In this case, it would've suggested to implement `onClick(View v)`

Comment: The casing of your code is very important. Though in some cases it is only for standard/readability sake, in many cases you will end up with broken code (as is this).

Comment: @Juan Cortes, thanks, stupid mistake, although beneficial as you commented _Keep in mind that the view may or may not be a Button, any View can potentially receive a click event_ and I learnt something new.

Comment: Added an extra tip ;)

Comment: @JuanCortés, thanks) Regarding your comment, if I set onClick listener like this `Button b = (Button) findViewById(R.id.hideb);         b.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() { public void onClick(View button) {` it is guaranteed that I'll get a button, not any view, right?

Comment: Yes, but only because it's the only View using that listener, you'll still need to cast that view to button if you need any button specific methods. Just check the views Id to know which one triggered the call

Comment: @JuanCortés, right thanks, like this `if (v.getId() == R.id.myBtnId) ` correct?